# Select when two tables reference the same table

Tags: sql

I have two tables, tSellers and tBuyers. They both have FK to a table tCity. How do I join and select city name from a buyer and a seller in a order table?

```
tOrder     tSeller   tBuyer   tCity
orderID    sellerID  buyerID  cityID
sellerID   cityID    cityID   name
buyerID

select o.orderID, c.name as buyerCity, c.name as sellerCity
from tOrder o
join tSeller s on s.sellerID = o.sellerID
join tBuyer b on b.buyerID = o.buyerID
join tCity c on c.cityID = ??
```

Expected output:

```
orderID  buyerCity sellerCity
      1  London    Paris
```

Comment: JOIN tcity twice. One time for Buyer, and one time for seller,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @jarlh 's comment:

Example of joining on City table twice, once for Seller (to get the city of the Seller), and once for Buyer (to get the city of the Buyer).

```
select o.orderID, buyerCity.name as BuyerCity, sellerCity.name as SellerCity
from tOrder o
join tSeller s on s.sellerID = o.sellerID
join tBuyer b on b.buyerID = o.buyerID
join tCity sellerCity on s.cityID =  sellerCity.cityID
join tCity buyerCity on b.cityID = buyerCity.cityID
```

Comment: For the asker: `s`, `b`, `o`, `sellerCity` and `buyerCity` are ["table aliases"](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp). They can be used for convenience, as with `o`, `s`, and `b`. Or they can be used to disambiguate, as in `sellerCity` and `buyerCity`.